# ¿Puedo crear dos constructores con la misma cantidad de parámetros y tipos de datos?

Tags: c++

Necesito crear estos dos constructores:
¿Hay alguna manera de crearlos sin que me de error por tener la misma cantidad de parámetros y tipos de parámetros?

```
class Nodo{
public:
    //constructor pais
    Nodo(string pCodPais, string pNombre){
        codPais = pCodPais;
        nombre = pNombre;
        siguiente = NULL;
        anterior = NULL;
        abajo = NULL;

    //constructor administrador
    Nodo(string pCodAdmin, string pNombre){
        codAdmin = pCodAdmin;
        nombre  = pNombre;
        siguiente = NULL;
        anterior = NULL;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Puedo crear dos constructores con la misma cantidad de parámetros y tipos de datos?

No. No puedes.

---

Pero tienes alternativas, cambia el orden de los parámetros y pon valores por defecto:

```
class Nodo{
    Nodo *siguiente = nullptr;
    Nodo *anterior = nullptr;
    Nodo *abajo = nullptr;
    string codPais = {};
    string nombre = {};
    string codAdmin = {};

public:
    Nodo(string pNombre, string pCodPais = {}, string pCodAdmin = {}) :
       codpais{pCodPais},
       nombre{pNombre},
       codAdmin{pCodAdmin}
    {}
};
```

De esta manera puedes construir:

```
Nodo apatrida("Nombre");
Nodo pais("Nombre", "Pais");
Nodo admin("Nombre", "", "Pais");
Nodo todo("Nombre", "Pais", "Admin");
```

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Puedo crear dos constructores con la misma cantidad de parámetros y tipos de datos?

No. No puedes.

---

Pero tienes alternativas. Usa clases auxiliares:

```
class Nodo {
public:
  struct pais {
    string codPais;
    string nombre;

    pais( string p, string n ) : codPais( p ), nombre( n ) { }
  };
  struct admin {
    string codAdmin;
    string nombre;
    admin( string a, string n ) : codAdmin( a ), nombre( n ) { }
  };

  //constructor pais
  Nodo( const pais &p ) {
    codPais = p.codPais;
    nombre = p.nombre;
    siguiente = NULL;
    anterior = NULL;
    abajo = NULL;
  }

  //constructor administrador
  Nodo( const admin &a ) {
    codAdmin = a.codAdmin,
    nombre  = a.nombre;
    siguiente = NULL;
    anterior = NULL;
  }
};

Nodo n1( Nodo::pais( "francia", "cucu" ) );
Nodo n2( Nodo::admin( "pepe", "cucu" ) );
```

Una variación de esta alternativa nos permite reducir código y hacerlo mas legible en caso de necesitar **muchos** argumentos:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct AlgoParams {
  string nombre;
  int largo = 0;
  int ancho = 0;

  AlgoParams &setLargo( int l ) { largo = l; return *this; }
  AlgoParams &setAncho( int a ) { ancho = a; return *this; }
  AlgoParams &setNombre( const string &s ) { nombre = s; return *this; }
};

struct Algo {
  Algo( AlgoParams & ) { }
};

Algo tmp( AlgoParams( )
          .setLargo( 10 )
          .setAncho( 5 )
          .setNombre( "cucu" ) );
```

Con lo cúal, los parámetros pasados son muy fácilmente localizables:

```
Algo tmp( AlgoParams( )
          .setLargo( 10 )
          .setAncho( 5 )
          .setNombre( "cucu" ) );
```

Y podemos combinarlo con los argumentos del propio constructor de `AlgoParams` (si tuviéramos un constructor adecuado):

```
struct AlgoParams {
  AlgoParams( const string &n1, const string &n2, int ) { ... }
  ...
};

Algo tmp( AlgoParams( "cucu", "pepe", 50 )
          .setLargo( 10 )
          .setAncho( 5 )
          .setNombre( "Madrid" ) );
```

Comment: Así mejor, genial ;). Yo personalmente prefiero la solución de tipado fuerte frente a la reorganización de los argumentos

Comment: Muchas gracias!